# wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.jar usage problem

Tags: java

Did anybody use **wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.jar** (http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.apache.maven.wagon/wagon-ssh/1.0-beta-2) library for scp upload files in Java ?
Can anybody give me example how to upload scp file with this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an SSH provider for [Maven Wagon](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/index.html). It doesn't make any sense unless used from a Maven context.

If you want to use SCP from Java, check out this previous question: [SCP via Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199624/scp-via-java)