# Simple FTP program in C or Java

Tags: java, c, ftp

I need to write a program in C or Java to transfer the files from windows to Linux machine. requirement is to connect Linux machine, authenticate, option for select mode , transfer the file and disconnect.

But I am not getting a simple C or Java program for it,at least connect it and transfer a simple file. can you tell me please from where I can start? or any simple example programs are available, any clue any link.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199624/scp-via-java

Answer (score 0):

search for sample client/server applications in Java or C as you prefer.Than you can start adding your communication protocol. You may be interested in asynchronous connections using select or other methods so the server will not hang waiting for client connections...

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is decide Java or C.

Deciding that, google for " FTP Libraries". Read through their documentation and proceed to build your client.

Keep in mind that you must be connecting to a machine that is accepting FTP connections (or perhaps you have to write the FTP server side as well? Get verification of this from whoever is giving you the assignment.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the  [**libcurl library**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). There is, in the examples section, [**an ftp client program**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html) that might suit you.