# Saving CSV file on UNIX Server from windows based Lotus Server using Lotus Scripting

Tags: windows, unix, csv, lotus, lotusscript

I have to write a script on Lotus Server which is on Windows server to save a csv file on UNIX server. I and Unix server path requires authentication. So can somebody help me or suggest me how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Siddhartha

Comment: Use ssh with certificates

Comment: Need more details on what you are trying to achieve. Are you using a view export, agent, XPages, etc? Where is the data coming from, what can the Unix server accept?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details. Presuming you can access the Unix folder from Windows Explorer, map the drive and let Windows store the password. Then access it through the mapped drive letter.

LotusScript can't write to UNC locations, so you need the drive letter.

That file will be probably picked up by another program.  CVS is the worst approach. You could offer to write to a Web Service or provide one.

**Update**
On Unix "access" more often than not doesn't mean a CIFS (a.k.a Windows share) access, but SSH (or FTP). For SSH you would want to:

- configure [SSH Keys](https://www.google.com/search?q=configure+ssh+keys), so you actually don't need username/password any more
- use a Java library [as asked on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199624/scp-via-java) before (or an [alternative](http://code.google.com/p/scp-java-client/))
- you also could write the file to a temp directory and call a cmd file for the [copy operation](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2006/09/23/command-line-scp-for-windows/)
- With a little care (make the cmd file configurable) the stuff will work when moving your Domino to Unix/Linux too

Let us know how it goes

Comment: problem is the client doesn't allow webservices for connecting and therefore no other option but to provide data in CSV file. As for mapping I can map folder of Unix server is possible than I will be able to work it out. Let me try it tomorrow my morning and come back to you with results.

Comment: If you go the mapped drive route, you may have issues if your Domino server is running as a service.

Comment: Well the server is mostly running as service but not 100% sure!

Comment: Unix boxes often only give you ssh access, so you would need to run scp.

Answer (score 0):

Could setting up a FTP server on Domino and accessing this from your UNIX server be an option ?

[Mindoo FTP server](http://bit.ly/12aeYVT)

Answer (score 0):

I once resolved this in two steps: 
1. Save the file to a temporary directory on the D omino server using LotusScript
2. Create a scheduled taks on the windowd serverr to copy the file to the second server

Advantages:
You can specify any user in the scheduled task and you don`t have to care about accessibility of the other server.

Disadvantages
Two separate processes.

Hope that helos.
Michael

Comment: Well original plan was this only but in last minute it was disallowed. So we are searching for alternate way!

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario which was very similar to yours, I did the following:

1. On the Windows Server, I created a Mapped Drive to the folder on the Unix OS. This also managed the Authentication.
2. In the LotusScript Agent, I extracted to this Mapped Drive, which worked 100%.