# How do I register the scp:// protocol in Java?

Tags: java, url, scp

I want to construct URL objects for `scp://...` urls. Currently, Java rejects these with `MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: scp`.

How can I get Java to construct these URLs without throwing exceptions?

Should I write a singleton handler and pass it as an option everywhere I construct URLs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199624/scp-via-java

Comment: Can you show us an example from your program?

Comment: @FredericClose Thank you Frederick. I'm already using ganymed for scp file transfer. But none of the scp libraries register the `scp://` protocol to the `URL` class. I have to do that as an extra step, hence the OP.