# File tranfer using SCP protocol

Tags: java, apache, scp, jsch

Need a Java program to copy multiple files from local windows to Linux server and vice versa(upload and download) .I have written a utility which works for single file transfer. But when it comes for the multiple file while listing the files in a directory. The files are not getting searched out, due to the issue directory separator. In windows it is '\' where as Linux '/'. Is there any free library which helps to do so?

It should be using SCP protocol. here is the snippet makes the main issue for me:

```
String files;
System.out.println("files=");
System.out.println();
File folder = new File(path);
System.out.println("folder="+folder);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
{

    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
    {
        files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        System.out.println("hello here are files");
        System.out.println(files);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57133202/597657

Answer (score 3):

[JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) might interest you. It's used for establishing a secure channel between two hosts - you can use it for SSH, SCP, SFTP, etc..

Example of establishing a connection: [example](http://wiki.jsch.org/index.php?Manual/Examples/SftpFileCopyExample)

Example for SCP (directly from JCraft): [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html)

This is how to get all properties(source and target absolute path from `File` object) for your files in a directory: http://pastebin.com/FXS9cHPW

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..the exmple shows for SFTP ...I need specifically SCP for multifile tranfer .Could you plz paste some example if have....

Comment: Of course. I edited in an example directly from the developers of JSch. Cheers!

Comment: Yes That works for single files...I am facing the issue for multile files ..say when i give *.txt ,*.Jepg ,or simply * it shuld work..Can you plz help me to modify accordingly.

Comment: Aren't you able to just do the same for all the files you need? Make a `List<File> files` which will contain them and then  `for(File thisFile : files){`.. I probably don't see the exact problem, sorry :(

Comment: Yes there the problem lies...When I try to list files using the above snippet you have given it is not listing any files due to cross plateform compatibility problem..

Comment: There is no cross platform compatibility problem. Source file with absolute path is a String as well as target path. It doesn't matter to JSch/SCP if you set a target path `C:\stuff\ ` or `/home/you/stuff/` it gets resolved on the target system. The only problem is if you don't know WHERE to copy the file in the first place and you're inputing a bad target folder, then you need to implement some sort of searching mechanism, but traversing the target system like this is not a good idea.

Comment: Or do you have a problem finding the files on your system?

Comment: String files;
          System.out.println();
          File folder = new File(rfile);
          System.out.println("folder="+folder);
          File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
          
          for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
          {
         
           if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
           {
           files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
           System.out.println("hello here are files");
           System.out.println(files);
              }
          }

Comment: Here when i give local path like rfile=C:\\Users\\SCP Utility\\Source\\ it list out all files...but where as when i give rfile=/root/softwares/ it doest search and list out all file inside the folder software. (this is used when i tranfer file from remote linux machine to windows local machine ...)I might be confusing you:(